# Node SerialPort

Tags: node.js, arduino-uno

I am using node serialport to communicate wtih Arduino Uno board. The following code is what I have used.

```
serialPort.on("open", function () {
  console.log('open');
  serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('data received: ' + data);
  });
  serialPort.write('s1\n', function(err, results) {
    if(err)
      console.log('err ' + err);
    else 
      console.log('results ' + results);
  });
});
```

When I give the input as 's1' from a terminal (like TeraTerm or Cool Term) I get a 0 or 1 as result. Basically, s1 is a command to read the status of a particular sensor. If the sensor is activated 1 is returned and if it is not 0 is returned.

However, in the above code snippet, I get the results as 3 (which is the number of characters in the string used for input. So, instead of 's1\n' if i put 's11\n' the result is returned as 4. What am I doing wrong here?

The .on('data') event is never triggered. But, the .on('open') event triggers, which indicates that the connection with the board is ok.

Comment: can you tell me what is the settings for parser like the below line    parser: com.parsers.readline('\r\n')    https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport/blob/master/examples/readdata.js

Comment: try setting it to '\n' only

Comment: Have tried that. Does not work.

Comment: Try sending a buffer not a string

Answer (score 0):

The write call is non-blocking and the result is `bytesWritten`, so the values you are seeing make sense. While double-checking the [docs](https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport/blob/3.1.2/README.md#write-buffer-callback) i also found this super useful note:

```
Note: Some devices like the Arduino reset when you open a connection 
to them. In these cases if you immediately write to the device they 
wont be ready to receive the data. This is often worked around by 
having the Arduino send a "ready" byte that your node program waits for 
before writing. You can also often get away with waiting around 400ms.
```

I can confirm that's true. We wait for a "--start--" message from the firmware before sending requests.

*Bonus*: watch out for leftover junk in the buffers when the Arduino resets. I've seen messages like "TemperatureUpdat--start--". 2 ideas for dealing with this:

- scan for "--start--" using an endsWith command, not an exact match. Downside being that you can't have a "--start--" in any other messages. be smart about the message you send and this becomes a non-issue).
- send a blank line, then a start message (e.g. "\nstart\n"). Downside being that you need to expect those 2 messages (i.e. an empty message or junk or a partial message followed by a valid start command)